# Is it possible to build a native android-to-android video chat app using webrtc?

Tags: android, webrtc

I see a lot of tutorials in the Internet teaching about android to browser or browser to browser webrtc application. Is it possible to build a native android-to-android video chat app using webrtc?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for establishing a connection between the devices before the call via peer-to-peer WebRTC solution you need STUN/TURN/ICE servers. 
They establish the route for communication between the devices. 
Once the route is established the devices communicate directly without participation of a server for passing the media streams.

To make it easier for you, you can look at or try some existing solutions, like [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/). 
They have peer-to-peer WebRTC solution for Android already implemented. 
So, maybe there is not need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official Android sample project AppRTCMobile provided here - https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/. However, the build process is tedious and the total download size exceeds 20 GB. The recommended way is to use the following dependency in your project.
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'

However, for video chat functionality you will need to refer AppRTCMobile source code. There is a clone of this project on GitHub updated for Oreo and ready to import in Android Studio. Check out this [link](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid).

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC uses ICE protocol for creating connection between two peers. It uses DTLS-SRTP for creating secure data exchange between peers.

Now both ICE protocol and DTLS-SRTP are protocols that can be implemented on any devices no matter what platform. You implement or use existing implementation of
ICE and DTLS-SRTP protocol on your android apps and communicate with each other.

When you read tutorials about implementation of WebRTC for communication between android app and browser, there the android app has the implementation of both ICE and DTLS-SRTP. So this android app can communicate with other android app having similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @tahlil great answer, you can also use a number of open source SDKs out there that already took the burden on bundling the WebRTC libraries and offering simple APIs for you to integrate Real Time Communications in your native app. One example of such SDK is the RestComm Android SDK 
See https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk and http://www.telestax.com/restcomm-client-android-sdk-beta-2-is-out/